# angularjs-slider two decimals in the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to add two decimals in the slider. Like `1.50` currently its `1.5`.

```
$scope.slider = {
  minValue: 1.5,
  options: {
    floor: 1.5,
    ceil: 4.5,
    step: 0.1,
    precision: 1,
    noSwitching: false,
    minLimit: 1.5,
    maxLimit: 90,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try like "{{value | number : fractionSize}}"

Example: {{12.52311 | number : 2}}, then it will be 12.52.

we can use it tags like  ng-model='val | number: 3'